# Batch File Calls VB Script & Passes Filename as String Only

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that calls a VB Script file.  This VB Script comes from MS Office Suite and is located in the Installed Folder.  My file calls the VB Script and pipes it to a file using the `>` symbol.  This works if your redirect is a string.  I was wondering how to redirect to a file using a variable.

I'm only including a small fraction of the code showing how I want it to work.

This, as written, works.  However I want my batch file to use a variable instead of the text in quotes.  In fact, my batch file creates the path depending on where the batch file is located.

```
::Create file and display on screen
Echo Writing Information to File: "OfficeStatus.txt"
Call cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus > OfficeStatus.txt
Echo.
```

When written as shown below, it does not work:

```
::Create file and display on screen
Echo Writing Information to File: "OfficeStatus.txt"
Call cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus > %_sLogFile%
Echo.
```

I don't know if the issue is because of the redirect not able to handle a variable or not.  An example of what might be in the variable:

```
_sLogFile=E:\UserName\Documents\Status\OfficeStatus.txt.
```

Any thoughts would be great.
The variable, by the way, correctly contains the path and filename... so that's not the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and **1.** elaborate (null-valued) "_… it does not work_" (some errors?), and **2.**  share a (sanitized) [mcve].

Comment: Should not be any issues using a variable.  All variables are expanded to their values before the command is executed.  So if it is not working then it is coming from something else within your batch file like using a code block or you are destroying the variable with an endlocal.

Comment: @NathanLegakis : rolled back your edit as it materially changed the destination filename. The leading backslash in the filename was removed, creating a relative filename (E:**.\\**username\whatever not E:\username\whatever as OP stated) and the very problem is likely to be the `username` part which you changed from OP's original. Good try, but in this case, it backfired.

Answer (score 1):

`it does not work` means `did not do what I expected` and unfortunately does not tell us what it *did* do.

Did it crash the system? Create an error message (If so, what message)? Create an output file in an unexpected place??

Personally, I'd suspect what you have concealed as `username`. Without knowing *precisely* what that text is, we start guessing, which isn't a logical approach. It doesn't have to be the real username, substitute `Fred Bloggs` for the real name to mask it if necessary.

I believe that `username` may either be `%username%` to retrieve the name from the system, or a real literal. The problem with this is that such names often contain spaces, you'd need to `"Enclose the full filename in quotes"`.

See - had you told us `_sLogFile=E:\Fred Bloggs\Documents\Status\OfficeStatus.txt` it would all have been a lot clearer - presuming that my guess as to the cause of the problem is correct.

Perhaps you should look for files named like `E:\Fred` which is where the expected output *may* have ended up.